# How can I extract all fields from my DB Connect results in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have configured a Database Input in DB Connect to pull in data from an Oracle view. A sample string from one of the events follows:

```
2023-02-28 15:40:50.760, AUDIT_TYPE="Standard", OS_USERNAME="Administrator", TERMINAL="unknown", DBUSERNAME="RACOON", CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME="SQL Developer", STATEMENT_ID="978", EVENT_TIMESTAMP="2023-02-28 18:40:50.76", ACTION_NAME="ALTER USER",  OBJECT_NAME="SPLUNK", SQL_TEXT="ALTER USER "SPLUNK" DEFAULT ROLE "CONNECT","AUDIT_VIEWER"", SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_USED="SYSDBA", CURRENT_USER="SYS", UNIFIED_AUDIT_POLICIES="ORA_SECURECONFIG"
```

However, when I run this search the fields are not correctly identified:

```
index=oracle_audit sourcetype=ID source=OracleAuditConnection
```

Specifically, what *should* be fields like TERMINAL, CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME, and OS_USERNAME (among many others) are not identified as fields. Additionally, the search is picking up values as fields, that should not be fields at all (often from the SQL_TEXT field). For example, "ACTIONS ALTER ON SPLUNK.BAT" is picked up as a field, rather than a value.

I can improve the results a little by using the following:

```
index=oracle_audit sourcetype=ID source=OracleAuditConnection  | extract pairdelim="\"{,}"
```

However, it still does not correctly identify all the fields. Nor does it work on the more complicated SQL_TEXT field, which may contain quotations and the equals signs at time.

What can I do to successfully have all of my fields extracted? Is there any trick I can do, given that I am using DB Connect?

Comment: The ID sourcetype must be missing some settings or existing settings need modifications.  Can you please share the props.conf settings for the sourcetype?

Answer (score 0):

As [RichG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227420/richg) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75606730/how-can-i-extract-all-fields-from-my-db-connect-results-in-splunk#comment133391431_75606730), seeing this sourcetype's `props.conf` is going to aid greatly

In lieu of that, however, you can start with the regular expression in this run-anywhere example:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="2023-02-28 15:40:50.760, AUDIT_TYPE=\"Standard\", OS_USERNAME=\"Administrator\", TERMINAL=\"unknown\", DBUSERNAME=\"RACOON\", CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME=\"SQL Developer\", STATEMENT_ID=\"978\", EVENT_TIMESTAMP=\"2023-02-28 18:40:50.76\", ACTION_NAME=\"ALTER USER\",  OBJECT_NAME=\"SPLUNK\", SQL_TEXT=\"ALTER USER \"SPLUNK\" DEFAULT ROLE \"CONNECT\",\"AUDIT_VIEWER\"\", SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_USED=\"SYSDBA\", CURRENT_USER=\"SYS\", UNIFIED_AUDIT_POLICIES=\"ORA_SECURECONFIG\""
| rex field=_raw "(?<_time>[^,]+),\s+AUDIT_TYPE=\"(?<audit_type>.+?)\",\s+\w+=\"(?<os_username>.+?)\",\s+"
```

Presuming your sample data string is accurate, you can keep going with the pattern presented to pull all the known fields out of the raw event

It's going to be *very* dependent upon knowing the order of your fields, of course, but this is an approach